# Create a custom view and call it programatically

Tags: android, view

Here are my custom view:

```
public class BuzzView extends View {

    /**
     * Constructor.  This version is only needed if you will be instantiating
     * the object manually (not from a layout XML file).
     * @param context
     */
    public BuzzView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.buzz_view, null);
    }
}
```

My buzz_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vignette_image_jauge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buzzomettre_sample" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Than i want to add my custom view from my FrameLayout in my activity:

```
 BuzzView buzzView = new BuzzView(MosaiqueListActivity.this);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.vignette_layout_jauge);
                frameLayout.addView(buzzView);
```

I am not getting my custom view in my RelativeLayout. Do you know why?

Comment: try adding layout params

Comment: doesn't work :(
buzzView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: is it possible to cast a ImageView to FrameLayout??

Comment: You need to Implement all three constructor from superclass. Also don't extends directly from View, user RelativeLayout as superclass instead

Comment: there is a classcastexception in the code you posted

Comment: @Thommy : only for including the class in an xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your BuzzView like this

```
public class CustomView {

private Context mContext;
private View mCustomView;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public CustomView(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView() {
    if(mCustomView==null) {
        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customView, null);
        //initialize all the child here
    }
    return mCustomView;
}
}
```

while adding your view just call getView() method like this in your activity

```
CustomView mCustomView = new CustomView(MyActivity.this);
layout.addView(mCustomView.getView(), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```